# nothing clickable outside of nav (a hrefs or click functions)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress-theming

I have a main nav and header, and inside these all links and click functions work fine.

But everything outside of that - inside main and footer - won't click.

This includes links, textareas, and click functions.

Hover effects also aren't working.

At first, I thought this was an issue with the z-indexes, and adjusting the z-indexes did bring back the ability to swipe on my slider, but not the ability to click links or interact with click functions

This is so bizarre to me. I have just noticed it and I've been working on the project a lot the past few days, so can't say exactly what I changed to stop them from working.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

website to help explain [helloxephia](http://helloxephia.com)

Comment: Look for unclosed `<tags>`.

Comment: share your code

Comment: It is very very difficult for anyone here to help without providing some code.

Comment: z-index probably, if you had partial success

Comment: it seems like the container have `pointer-events:none`. try to give to achilds `pointer-events:auto`. or something invisible cover the page and cache the events. in this case give to him `pointer-events:none`.  anyway can be nice if you share your code..

Comment: Sorry, new here! My website is [link](http://www.helloxephia.com), but I'm not sure what snippets I can share to recreate the problem

Comment: I removed the z-index for div with class .nav-overlay and it seems to be clickable. Just try and see.

Comment: Of course, I feel so silly. Thanks @Hrishikesh! That worked, and adding display none to the overlay before it's shown allowed me to keep the z-index without it blocking the rest of the site

Comment: @xee thats cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="nav-overlay"`enter code here`></div>
```

you have to hide this element. currently this element is show. that's the reason you cannot click outside of header.

Comment: This turned out to be the problem - I had it set to 0 opacity but forgot to hide it. Thanks again! Also thanks everyone for all the help in the comments too~